# Assigning Alamofire result to array

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire

I am trying to assign the result that is retrieved by Alamofire to an array, and have come across an issue.

I am using the Stripe API for products, it returns back a JSON object called "data:", I am trying to assign that data object only to that products array I have.

Here's my code

```swift
var products: [Product] = []
let stripeProducts = "stripe-products-api"

func createArray() {
  let stripeAuthHeader: HTTPHeaders = []

  AF.request(stripeProducts, headers: stripeAuthHeader).responseJSON {
     switch response.result {
     case .failure(let error):
       print(error)
     case .success:
       self.products = response.data \\ trying to access the data object from the JSON data
       print(self.products)
     }
  }
}
```

JSON:

```
 "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "prod_123456",
      "object": "product",
      "active": true,
      "attributes": [

      ],
      "created": 1590423835,
      "description": "Test",
      "images": [
        ""
      ],
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
        "address": "Test"
      },
      "name": "Blue Jeans",
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "type": "service",
      "unit_label": null,
      "updated": 1590653248
    }
]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the issue or error you're running into?

Comment: @NewDev I am unable to give the created products variable the "data" json object from stripe's response.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @NewDev Sorry, it's this: "Cannot assign value of type 'AFDataResponse<Any>'

Comment: `response.data` is of type `AFDataResponse<Any>`? `response.data` should give you an object you can cast into an `[Any]` array or `[String: Any]` dictionary - depending on what you're expecting to get

Comment: And you probably should look into `responseDecodable`, which makes it easier, if your `Product` type conforms to Decodable

Comment: @NewDev Thanks, I will try looking more into that, see what I can come up with

Comment: can you post your json ?

Comment: @jawadAli I have attached my JSON in the main post

Comment: have you created struct to decode this data ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Struct of Products

```
  struct Datum: Decodable {
    let id, object: String
    let active: Bool
    let created: Int
    let datumDescription: String
    let images: [String]
    let livemode: Bool
    let metadata: Metadata
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let updated: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, object, active, created
        case datumDescription = "description"
        case images, livemode, metadata, name
        case type
        case updated
    }
}

// MARK: - Metadata
struct Metadata: Decodable {
    let address: String
}
```

Then parse it like this

```
let products = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Products.self, from: response.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however is there a reason it says Type 'Datum' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' as well as use of undeclared type 'JSONAny' and 'JSONNull'?

Comment: Sorry, for some odd reason Type 'Datum' Does not conform to protocol 'Decodable', any reason why this happens?

Comment: sorry it was my fault .. try it now

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this to be fair, I am not doing a great job, sorry..